# How to submit a form with ajax if two parameters are set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a simple rails form and want to submit the form when the two parameters are set without the click of a submit button. How can i write a simple jquery ajax request to do this.

my form below is

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span7">
    <%= form_tag search_by_group_admin_codes_path, :method => :get, class: "well form-inline" do %>
        <p class="f_legend">Black List Codes</p>
        <div class="input-prepend">
          <span class="add-on ad-on-icon"><i class="icon-qrcode"></i></span>
          <%= text_field_tag 'q', @q, placeholder: "between", id: "q"  %>
          <%= text_field_tag 's', @s, placeholder: "to", id: "s"  %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help thanks? i am Not too good at ajax in rails without the click of a button

Comment: I hope below link will help you. http://railskey.wordpress.com/2012/09/07/rails-3-how-to-redirect_to-in-ajax-call/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function(){
  $('input').on("input", checkInput)
  //$('input').on("keyup", checkInput)
})

function checkInput(ev){
    if($('#q').val != '' && $('#q').val().length == 8 &&  $('#s').val != '' && $('#s').val().length == 8 )
    {
        $(this).closest('form').submit()
    }
}
```